# Help with derive geodesic equation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-riemannian manifold and $p,q\in M$. Suppose $\alpha:[a,b]\to M$ a smooth curve on $M$ such that $\alpha(a)=p$ and $\alpha(b)=q$. If we consider:
$$L[H(s,\cdot)]=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{H(s,t)}(\partial_t H,\partial_tH)}$$
as a function of $s$, where $H:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times (a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an smooth map which satisfies:

(i) $H(0,\cdot)=\alpha$ in $[a,b]$

(ii) $H(s,a)=p$ and $H(s,b)=q$.

**My question is:**

If I prove that there exists an unique $\alpha_0$ (exept reparametrization) such that:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\Big(L[H(s,\cdot)]\Big)_{s=0}=0$$
How can I conclude that does not exists any $\beta$ curve in $M$ with $\beta(a)=p$ and $\beta(b)=q$ s.t. $long(\alpha)=long(\beta)$?

I can't write exactly why this happend. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you got the right sign? Currently your statement is trivially false. Your previous statement is a little be less trivially false.

Comment: More precisely, take $N$ the sphere and $p,q$ almost antipodes. There are two geodesics connecting $p, q$. Let $M$ be the sphere with a portion removed so that the shortest geodesic is cut off. Then the remaining geodesic is the unique critical point to the length functional connecting $p$ and $q$, but there are curves in $M$ with lengths longer, shorter, and equal to the remaining geodesic.

Comment: So if you have other assumptions on $M$ that you forgot to give: please include them.

Comment: is it only true if $p$ and $q$ are in the same local chart?

Comment: No. Since my example above uses the sphere with at least one point removed, the manifold $M$ can be represented with one single chart. To get the desired conclusion, you need to use some version of the [mountain pass lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem). This would be satisfied if you know $a_0$ is the unique _minimizing_ geodesic, or if you know that the index form (roughly, the Hessian of L[H] at $a_0$) is positive definite.